# adding movieClip to the stage from a child class

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to create a separate class which draws a rectangle and add it to the stage, but the problem is when I try to do this from the class itself I got nothing on the stage.

my setup as follow:

Main.fla which has the document class Main.as:

```
package 
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import Window;
public class Main extends Sprite 
{

    public function Main():void 
    {
        var newWindow:Window = new Window();

    }

}

}
```

the class where the MovieClip isadded

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class Window extends Sprite {

    public function Window(x:Number= 0, y:Number= 0, width:Number = 100, height:Number=100,title:String="Window"):void {
        var  newWindow:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        addChild(newWindow);
        newWindow.graphics.beginFill(0xFF9966, 1);
        newWindow.graphics.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
        trace("Instance created");      
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see problems with currently posted code. Did you try adding `newWindow` to stage instead of `this` and fail? :)

Comment: when I try to add it to the stage I got following error
    `TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.`

Comment: Right, when you first create a class instance its `stage` property is null. Only the document class has access to stage. You'd better use `this.addChild(xxx)` instead of adding to stage, because there are circumstances when your SWF might be embedded in another, and then you won't get the proper stage anyway. Also, adding to `this` will help you manage your windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you cannot access `stage` from the newly created object because it's not aware of the stage ever existing. The only thing you can add a child in there is to `this`. But, when you properly nest objects into containers, you can do more powerful things in an instant, like for example moving a complicated window by a single assignment of `x` and `y` properties of the container. So, the thing you have to do is `addChild(newWindow)` in your main class.

```
package 
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import Window;
public class Main extends Sprite 
{

    public function Main()
    {  
        var newWindow:Window = new Window();
        addChild(newWindow); // THIS
        // also here you can do "newWindow.x=100;" for example
    }

}

}
```

Comment: it worked when I add it from the document class, but I am little bit confuse though, when I first added the MovieClip from the `Window` class the newly created MovieClip wasn't added to the Stage display list? because it is not rendered? why? I tried to use `this` it didn't worked. sorry if I may seems stupid but I am just starting to learn as3 so bear with me

Comment: Yes, because you had to add `this` to the stage display list first. See, the hierarchy of the display list starts from stage, and nests as deep as you build it. In your case it looks like `stage -> newWindow (Window) -> newWindow (MovieClip)`. See, these `newWindow`s are two different objects. You have completed building the second arrow via `addChild(newWindow)` inside `Window` class constructor, but until the first arrow isn't built, the rectangle of `newWindow` is not displayed because `stage` isn't aware of newly created MCs.